# Do you still write HTML/CSS files if you're using React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I can't seem to understand the workflow with react.js. Do you still need to write HTML and CSS straight up?

Comment: CSS: Yes. HTML: Kind of... it depends on how efficient you want the first rendering to be.

Comment: Yes, but the HTML is written in the .js files and the css is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, do you still have to write HTML and CSS, but you have different workflow for both

**HTML** you write on render function inside your javascript file, as example below:

```
const HelloMessage = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>Hello { props.name }</div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Jane" />, mountNode);
```

**CSS** you can write in two ways

1. As [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), you can code a sass/less/stylus or even css file, then  you import inside your javascript file and using classname *(npm module)* you call it
2. As [styled component](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components), in this case you code css as a JSON inside your javascript file

Comment: Writing HTML this way is so weird 